# Rolling your own Applicatives with Data.Functor.Compose

Tags: haskell

I was playing around with the wonderful answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702513/2684007). I naively expected this to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.Functor.Compose
import Control.Monad

class (Functor f, Functor g) => Adjoint f g where
    counit :: f (g a) -> a
    unit   :: a -> g (f a)

instance (Adjoint f g) => Monad (Compose g f) where
    return x = Compose $ unit x
    x >>= f  = Compose . fmap counit . getCompose $ fmap (getCompose . f) x
```

It doesn't, though. I get the following error:

```
adjoint.hs:10:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (Applicative g)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
```

Here's what seems to be happening. GHC requires all `Monad`s to have an `Applicative` instance, so the compiler goes looking for one for `Compose g f`.
 [`Data.Functor.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Data-Functor-Compose.html#Compose) defines such an instance, but it requires `g` (and `f`) to be `Applicative`:

```
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure x = Compose (pure (pure x))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose ((<*>) <$> f <*> x)
```

But in the general case, `Compose g f` can be a `Monad` (and thereby `Applicative`) even when `g` and `f` aren't both `Applicative`. The usual example is when `f` is `(,) s`, and `g` is `(->) s`. Then `Compose g f` is the `State` `Monad`, even though `(,) s` isn't (always) `Applicative`.

This seems a bit suboptimal. For one, it would be nice to use `Adjoint` to define `Monad` instances for two `Functor`s that aren't both `Applicative`. More generally, though, there are ways for the composition of two `Functors` to be `Applicative`, even when one or both of them fails to be. Currently, though, the way that GHC behaves, combined with the way `Data.Functor.Compose` is set up, *precludes you from ever realizing these use cases*. If you try to define an `Applicative` instance for any `Compose g f`, GHC will complain about a duplicate instance declaration.

The obvious solution is just to roll your own version of `Data.Functor.Compose` with the `Applicative` lines scrapped. That's straightforward enough, if a bit hacky. Are there other more principled ways to approach the issue?

Comment: I think your obvious solution is correct.  When working with typeclasses, we need to extend our concept of a type from "set-like" to "algebraic-structure-like".  `Compose g f` is already an `Applicative` in one way, and you propose to make it one in a different way.  In this way of thinking, it's now a different type -- much like we use `Sum Int` to indicate that we mean to take the `Monoid` that adds as opposed to the several other possibilities.

Comment: Can you say what you mean by "hacky"? Why don't you like the "roll your own `Compose`" solution?

Comment: The issue might be that I've been misconstruing type class parameters. I've been reading `instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g)` as "whenever `f` and `g` are `Applicative`, so is `Compose f g`. So if either `f` or `g` isn't known to be `Applicative`, GHC shouldn't conclude that `Compose f g` is. Obviously this isn't what's happening! But it seems like sensible enough behavior (though maybe it has bad consequences downstream). So perhaps my resistance to "roll your own `Compose`" is just me being stubborn about my naive understanding of type class parameters.

Comment: @SimonC Right. One could definitely imagine a type class system with that behavior, and nothing semantically would go wrong. The problem is that then finding an instance involves a backtracking search, and the committee wanted to avoid that both to avoid forcing a complex implementation (remember, at the time, this was the first type class system in existence and nobody knew how complicated it would be!) and to avoid users discovering deep in a development that long instance searches were causing enormous compilation times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if you need a different instance, you need a new type. Should be pretty straightforward; just a few lines of code:

```
newtype AdjointCompose f g a = AdjointCompose { runAdjointCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (AdjointCompose f g) where
    fmap = liftM

instance Adjoint f g => Applicative (AdjointCompose g f) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Adjoint f g => Monad (AdjointCompose g f) where
    -- as in your proposed instance
```

Now you can have your cake and eat it, too: when you want the composition of `Applicative`s, use `Compose`, and when you want the `Applicative` you get from adjointness, use `AdjointCompose`.

If you want some of the other instances that `Compose` defines for free, you could write `AdjointCompose` as a newtype over `Compose` instead and get them via `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.

Comment: The `Functor` instance should probably be the usual derived one for efficiency, I imagine.