# Adjunction underlying the Tardis monad

Tags: haskell, categories, monads, category-theory

We know that [monads come from adjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Monads_and_adjunctions) (and this was [discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697320/monads-as-adjunctions?noredirect=1&lq=1) too).  The usual monads in programming use come from well-known adjunctions. So where does the [Tardis](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tardis-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Tardis.html) monad come from? (`RevState` would be nice to know about too).

Comment: I strongly suspect `RevState` will be an adjunction between **Hask** and **Hask**Op.